# Lua reading table as array in C returns nil for indices

Tags: arrays, c, lua

I want to share a lua table given as an argument for a registered C function and convert this table to an C array.
Lua 5.4.

The table length is correctly retrieved, however the indices type are always nil.

This is my C code:

```
static int myFunction(lua_State *L)
{

  uint16 targetAddress = lua_tointeger(L, 1);

  // array1 - pay attention to use of 2, -1, and 1.
  if (lua_istable(L, 2) != 0)
  {
      unsigned int userDataSize = lua_rawlen(L, 2);

      ESP_LOGE(TAG, "length: %d",userDataSize);

      uint8_t *userData = (uint8_t *)malloc(userDataSize * sizeof(uint8_t));

      if (!userData)
      {
          ESP_LOGE(TAG, "GenericRequest Failed to allocate memory");
      }

      for (unsigned int i = 0; i < userDataSize; i++)
      {
              lua_rawgeti(L, 2, i + 1); // Lua uses 1-based indices.

              ESP_LOGE(TAG, "type %s", luaL_typename(L, -1));

              ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Val: %f", lua_tonumber(L, -1));
              userData[i] = (uint8_t)lua_tonumber(L, -1);
              ESP_LOGI(TAG, "%d: %d", i, userData[i]);

              lua_pop(L, 1); // Pop the Lua value from the stack
      }

      ESP_LOGI(TAG, "TA: 0x%X data:", targetAddress);
      ESP_LOG_BUFFER_HEX(TAG, userData, userDataSize);

      free(userData);
  }
  else
  {
      ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Argument #2 expected table");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

And this my lua script:

```
print(\"Hello from Lua\") 
mylib.myFunction(0xA98, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5})
```

I also tried to make the table as a local variable first and pass the variable name to myFunction

The log output shows:
Hello from Lua
E (3572) BSW: length: 5
E (3573) BSW: type nil
E (3573) BSW: Val: 0.000000
I (3573) BSW: 0: 0
E (3576) BSW: type nil
E (3579) BSW: Val: 0.000000
I (3583) BSW: 1: 0
E (3586) BSW: type nil
E (3590) BSW: Val: 0.000000
I (3594) BSW: 2: 0
E (3602) BSW: type nil
E (3605) BSW: Val: 0.000000
I (3609) BSW: 3: 0
E (3612) BSW: type nil
E (3615) BSW: Val: 0.000000
I (3619) BSW: 4: 0
I (3622) BSW: TA: 0xA98 data:
I (3627) BSW: 00 00 00 00 00

**EDIT:**
The following code works, explanations appreciated. Thanks

```
      uint16 targetAddress = lua_tointeger(L, 1);
      printf("TA: 0x%X \n", targetAddress);


          uint8_t idx_table = 2;
          // Check if the first argument is a table
          if (!lua_istable(L, idx_table)) {
              printf("Not a table.\n");
              return 0;
          }

          // Push nil onto the stack to start the iteration
          lua_pushnil(L);

          // Iterate through the table using lua_next
          while (lua_next(L, idx_table) != 0) {
              // 'key' is at index -2 and 'value' is at index -1
              if (lua_isinteger(L, -1)) {
                  printf("Value: %d\n", lua_tointeger(L, -1));
              } else if (lua_isstring(L, -1)) {
                  printf("Value: %s\n", lua_tostring(L, -1));
              }

              // Pop the value, leaving the key on top for the next iteration
              lua_pop(L, 1);
          }

          // No need to pop the table explicitly, as it's the first argument

          return 0;
```

Comment: This code looks good, but it does not match the output you present. Please show the actual code.

Comment: @Ctx yes sorry, for testing I was basically skipping the if (!lua_isnumber(L, -1)) check.
Edited the code.

Comment: I do not see a problem here, this ought to work. Please provide more context, maybe this reveals the cause.

Comment: hey @Ctx I tested another method, which gives me the actual values. I would appreciate it if you could give an explanation for this.

Comment: I tried your first code, and it worked.